# Showing MessageBox in a separate thread and automatically closing this thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I work with WPF application and legacy code. There is a application that is used for dispensing liquids. With each new dosing should be checked whether the cup was replaced by a dispenser, and if not, display a message on the need to change the cup. Dispenser has a change cup sensor. I need close automatically MessageBox, if cup was changed. For this running two threads. In first is a MessageBox, in another survey process dispenser. This is code:

```
public bool CheckChangeCupInThread()
{
    if (_dispenser.Status.CupChanged == DispenserEnums.CupChanged.False)
    {
        var cupFormThread = new ThreadStart(CupWaitChangeForm);
        var cupFormWaiter = new Thread(cupFormThread) {IsBackground = true};
        cupFormWaiter.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        var cupThread = new ThreadStart(WaitForCupChange);
        var cupWaiter = new Thread(cupThread) {IsBackground = true};
        cupWaiter.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        cupFormWaiter.Start();
        cupWaiter.Start();

        do
        {
            //Wait for Cup to be changed or Cancel
        } while (cupFormWaiter.IsAlive && cupWaiter.IsAlive);

        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        if (cupFormWaiter.IsAlive)
        {
            cupFormWaiter.Abort();
        }
        if (cupWaiter.IsAlive)
        {
            _dispenser.SurveillanceWorker.Continue = false;
            cupWaiter.Join(200);
            return false;
        }
        watch.Stop();
    }
    return true;
}

private void WaitForCupChange()
{
    do
    {
        _dispenser.GetStatus();
    } while (_dispenser.Status.CupChanged == DispenserEnums.CupChanged.False);
}

private void CupWaitChangeForm()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Change please the cup", "Cup сhange", MessageBoxButtons.Cancel);
}
```

This code earlier has been used in a large class with more than 4000 lines of code. I did refactoring and placed this code in a separate class. Now, after the change of the cup go a program crash, not in this place, but somewhere farther in code. The most interesting thing that often happens when working with application in Windows 10, this is all but not happens in Windows 7. I am novice in multithreading and can not understand, how can I solve this problem. I tried it with tasks and token, but token can not close thread with MessageBox until pressed the button. Thanks

Comment: There's no point in creating another thread if you're just going to have another thread sit around spinning in a loop until it's done.  Just do the work in the original thread.

Comment: I think I need two threads, because I have two events - or a cup is changed, or the button "Cancel" in MessageBox clicked. How do I watching both?

Comment: You don't need any additional thread.  You should be structuring your code so that it is asynchronous, and that you are notified of a change, rather than sitting there in a loop cooking an egg on your CPU instead of using it for something productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved a problem. Now MessageBox closed, if Task1 finished. Or I close MessageBox, then terminate Task1

```
internal class Program
{
    public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action<object> action = (object obj) =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                i++;
            } while (i < 10);
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has been finished");
        };

        Action<object> action1 = (object obj) =>
        {
            DialogResult result = DialogResult.OK;
            do
            {
                result = MessageBox.Show("This is task2", "Task2", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
            } while (result != DialogResult.Cancel);
            Console.WriteLine("t2 has been finished");
        };

        var tasks = new Task[2];
        var source1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token1 = source1.Token;
        Task t1 = new Task(action, "alpha", token1);
        tasks[0] = t1;
        Task t2 = new Task(action1, "betha");
        tasks[1] = t2;

        t1.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("t1 has been launched. (Main Thread={0})",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        t2.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("t2 has been launched. (Main Thread={0})",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        try
        {
            int index = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
            if (t1.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
                source1.Cancel();
            if (t2.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
                CloseMessage();
            Console.WriteLine("Task #{0} completed first.\n", tasks[index].Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Status of all tasks:");
            foreach (var t in tasks)
                Console.WriteLine("   Task #{0}: {1}", t.Id, t.Status);
        }
        catch (AggregateException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred.");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CloseMessage()
    {
        int window = FindWindow(null, "Task2");
        if (window != 0)
            SendMessage(window, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
    }
}
```